# How to implement saving function to my "saving button" in my drawing program?

Tags: java, save, drawing

So as you can see my painting program is working properly. It can draw shapes like oval and rectangle (oval shape looks kinda bug though if anyone could help me fix it as well). I want to know how to make a saving button. Right now, I don't even know what I'm doing. I have been research on how to save a drawn image, but none of the code on internet has an example of a java made drawing program with saving function. So here's my code:

Shapeframe class

```js
package com.comp2526.assign2c.a.a00892238;



import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


/**
 * This class creates the painting program's toolbar, buttons and stuffs.
 * @author Fu Han
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class ShapeFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 /**
  * the white board
  */
 static DrawPad drawboard;
 /**
  * the constant string 'save'.
  */
 static final private String SAVE = "Save";
 /**
  * the constant string 'save as'.
  */
    static final private String SAVE_AS = "Save As";
    /**
  * the constant string 'new'.
  */
    static final private String NEW = "New";
    /**
  * the constant string 'color'.
  */
    static final private String color = "Color";
    /**
     * string oval for easy access for buttons.
     */
    static String oval = new String("oval");
    /**
     * string line for easy access for buttons.
     */
    static String line = new String("line");
    /**
     * string rectangle for easy access for buttons.
     */
    static String rectangle = new String("rectangle");
    /**
     * string square for easy access for buttons.
     */
    static String square = new String("square");
    /**
     * color.
     */
    Color currentColor;
    /**
     * ShapeFrame constructor.
     */
 public ShapeFrame(){
  super();
 }
 /**
  * method that add buttons.
  * @param toolBar Jtoolbar.
  * @param btn Jbuttons.
  */
 protected void addButtons(JToolBar toolBar, JButton btn) {
        toolBar.add(btn);
    }
 
 /**
  * method that add radio buttons.
  * @param toolBar Jtoolbar.
  * @param btn JRadioButton.
  */
 protected void addRadioButtons(JToolBar toolBar, JRadioButton btn) {
        toolBar.add(btn); 
    }
 
 /**
  * method that creates button.
  * @param btnNam button name.
  * @param actionCommand calling from string constant.
  * @param toolTipText the message that will appear if cursor was hover over.
  * @param altText alternative text.
  * @return button Jbutton.
  */
 protected JButton btnmaker(String btnNam, String actionCommand, String toolTipText, String altText) {

       //Create and initialize the button.
         JButton button = new JButton(btnNam);
        button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
       button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
          button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }
 
 /**
  * action performed when clicked button.
  * @param e mouse click.
  */
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
 
 public static void savebtn(DrawPad dp) {
     DrawPad dp1 = dp;
     //String sb = "gg";
/*
     public void save() throws IOException{
         ImageIO.write(paintImage, "PNG", new File("filename.png"));
     }*/
     JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
     chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));

     int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

     if (retrieval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
         try {
             //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".png");
             //fw.write(sb.toString());
             //fw.close();
          ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) dp1.image, "PNG", new File("filename.png"));
          ImageIo.
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     
 }
 
 /**
  * editlistener for menu bar.
  * @author Fu Han
  *
  */
    private class EditListener implements ActionListener {
     /**
      * action performed when clicking menu button.
      * @param e mouse click.
      */
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getActionCommand() == SAVE) {
       System.out.print("save");
      }else{
       System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
     }
 }
    }
 /**
  * radio listener for the radio buttons.
  * @author Fu Han
  *
  */
   private class RadioListener implements ActionListener{
    /**
     * action performed when click the button.
     * @param e mouse click.
     */
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   System.out.print("ActionEvent received: ");
   if (e.getActionCommand() == oval) {
   System.out.println(oval + " pressed.");
   drawboard.line = false;
   drawboard.rectangle = false;
   drawboard.square = false;
   drawboard.oval = true;
   }else if(e.getActionCommand() == rectangle){
   System.out.println(rectangle + " pressed.");
   drawboard.line = false;
   drawboard.rectangle = true;
   drawboard.square = false;
   drawboard.oval = false;
   }else if(e.getActionCommand() == square){
   System.out.println(square + " pressed.");
   drawboard.line = false;
   drawboard.rectangle = false;
   drawboard.square = true;
   drawboard.oval = false;
   }else{
   System.out.println(line + " pressed.");
   drawboard.line = true;
   drawboard.rectangle = false;
   drawboard.square = false;
   drawboard.oval = false;
   }
   }
}
/**
 * method for when changes of states that happened after clicking.
 * @param e mouse click.
 */
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    }

/**
 * method for selecting color.
 */
private void selectColor(){
 Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(
   ShapeFrame.this,
            "Choose New Background Color",
            currentColor);
 if(newColor != null){
  currentColor = newColor;
 }
 
}
 
 /**
  * GUI initialization.
  */
 public void init(){
  
  Container content = getContentPane();
  //Creates a new container
  content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  //sets the layout
  
  final DrawPad drawPad = new DrawPad();
  //creates a new padDraw, which is pretty much the paint program
  
  content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
  JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

  EditListener l = new EditListener();
        JMenu filem = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem mi;
        mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("New", 'n'));
        mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        mi.addActionListener(l);
        mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Open", 'o'));
        mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        mi.addActionListener(l);
        mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Save", 's'));
        mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        mi.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    savebtn(drawPad);
    
   }
   
  });
        mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Save As", 'a'));
        mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        mi.addActionListener(l);
        mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Exit", 'e'));
        mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        mi.addActionListener(l);  
        
        JMenu shapem = new JMenu("Shape");
        JMenuItem smi;
        smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Line", 'l'));
        smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        smi.addActionListener(l);
        smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Circle", 'c'));
        smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        smi.addActionListener(l);
        smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Rectangle", 'r'));
        smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_U, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        smi.addActionListener(l);
        smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Square", 'q'));
        smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_I, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        smi.addActionListener(l);
        smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Shape Picker", 'p'));
        smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_L, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        smi.addActionListener(l);
        
        menubar.add(filem);
        menubar.add(shapem);     
        menubar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());


        setJMenuBar(menubar);

   
        //Create the toolbar.
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  
        JButton saveBtn = btnmaker("Save",SAVE, "save your paint", "Save");
  JButton saveAsBtn = btnmaker("Save As",SAVE_AS, "save your paint to?","Save As");
  JButton NewBtn = btnmaker("New",NEW,"new paint","New");
  
  JButton colorbtn = btnmaker("Color",color,"choose color","Color");
  colorbtn.setToolTipText("Click this button to select colors.");
  
  colorbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {    
    selectColor();
    drawPad.color(currentColor);
   }
   
  });
  

  
  RadioListener myListener = new RadioListener();
  JRadioButton ovalShape = new JRadioButton(oval);
  ovalShape.addActionListener(myListener);
  ovalShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  ovalShape.setActionCommand(oval);
  
  //add(ovalShape);
  
  JRadioButton rectangleShape = new JRadioButton(rectangle);
  rectangleShape.addActionListener(myListener);
  rectangleShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  rectangleShape.setActionCommand(rectangle);
  //add(rectangleShape);
  
  JRadioButton squareShape = new JRadioButton(square);
  squareShape.addActionListener(myListener);
  squareShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  squareShape.setActionCommand(square);
  //add(squareShape);
  
  JRadioButton lineShape = new JRadioButton(line);
  lineShape.addActionListener(myListener);
  lineShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
  lineShape.setActionCommand(line);
  lineShape.setSelected(true);
  //add(lineShape);
  
  
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(ovalShape);
        group.add(lineShape);
        group.add(rectangleShape);
        group.add(squareShape);
        
  JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("File");
        JToolBar toolBar2 = new JToolBar("Shape",JToolBar.VERTICAL);
        JToolBar toolbar3 = new JToolBar("colors",JToolBar.VERTICAL);

        
        addButtons(toolBar,saveBtn);
        addButtons(toolBar,saveAsBtn);
        addButtons(toolBar,NewBtn);
        addRadioButtons(toolBar2,ovalShape);
        addRadioButtons(toolBar2,lineShape);
        addRadioButtons(toolBar2,rectangleShape);
        addRadioButtons(toolBar2,squareShape);
        addButtons(toolbar3,colorbtn);


        panel.add(toolBar);
        panel2.add(toolBar2);
        panel2.add(toolbar3);
        

        content.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        content.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
 }
}
```

DrawPad class:

```js
package com.comp2526.assign2c.a.a00892238;


import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
/**
 * the draw pad class for drawing
 * @author Fu Han
 * @version 1.0
 */
class DrawPad extends JComponent{
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 /**
  * image
  */
 Image image;
 /**
  * what user will be using to draw on
  */
 Rectangle r = null;
 Oval o = null;
 Graphics2D graphics2D;
 ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangleList = null;
 /**
  *mouse coordinates
  */
 static boolean rectangle = false;
 static boolean oval = false;
 static boolean line = false;
 static boolean square = false;
 int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
 /**
  * shape object
  */

 /**
  * constructor
  */
 public DrawPad(){
  rectangleList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
  setDoubleBuffered(false);
  addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    oldX = e.getX();
    oldY = e.getY();
    if(rectangle == true){
     r = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(),
                   e.getX(), e.getY(), graphics2D.getColor());
    }else if(oval == true){
     o = new Oval(e.getX(), e.getY(),
                   e.getX(), e.getY(), graphics2D.getColor());
    }
   }
  });
  //if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
  //coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates
  addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    currentX = e.getX();
    currentY = e.getY();
    if(graphics2D != null){
    if(rectangle == true){
     
     r = new Rectangle(r.getX1(),
                   r.getY1(), e.getX(), e.getY(),
                   r.getColor());
     drawRectangle(r,graphics2D);
     rectangleList.add(new Rectangle(r.getX1(),
                   r.getY1(), e.getX(), e.getY(),
                   graphics2D.getColor()));
     repaint();
     oval = false;
     line = false;
     square = false;
    }
    else if(line == true){
     graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
     repaint();
     oldX = currentX;
     oldY = currentY;
     rectangle = false;
     oval = false;
     square = false;
    }
    else if(oval == true){
     o = new Oval(o.getX1(), o.getY1(),
                   e.getX(), e.getY(), o.getColor());
     drawOval(o,graphics2D);
     repaint();
     rectangle = false;
     square = false;
     line = false;
    }
       }
    
    }
    
  });
  //while the mouse is dragged it sets currentX & currentY as the mouses x and y
  //then it draws a line at the coordinates
  //it repaints it and sets oldX and oldY as currentX and currentY
 }

 /**
  * painting dot
  * @param g Graphic
  */
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  if(image == null){
   image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
   graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
   graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
   clear();

  }
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
  
   }
 
 public void clear(){
  graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
  graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
  graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
  repaint();
 }
 
 public void drawRectangle(Rectangle rek, Graphics gr) {
     Graphics2D g = null;
     if (gr instanceof Graphics2D) {
         g = (Graphics2D) gr;
     }
     else{ return; }
     //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
     g.drawRect(rek.getX1(), rek.getY1(), rek.getWidth(), rek.getHeight());
     g.setColor(graphics2D.getColor());
     g.fillRect(rek.getX1(), rek.getY1(), rek.getWidth(), rek.getHeight());
    //g.drawLine(rek.getX1(), rek.getY1(), rek.getX2(), rek.getY1());
    //g.drawLine(rek.getX1(), rek.getY1(), rek.getX1(), rek.getY2());
    //g.drawLine(rek.getX2(), rek.getY2(), rek.getX2(), rek.getY1());
    // g.drawLine(rek.getX2(), rek.getY2(), rek.getX1(), rek.getY2());
 }
 
 public void drawOval(Oval ovo, Graphics gr) {
     Graphics2D g = null;
     if (gr instanceof Graphics2D) {
         g = (Graphics2D) gr;
     }
     else{ return; }
     //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
     g.drawOval(ovo.getX1(), ovo.getY1(), ovo.getWidth(), ovo.getHeight());
     g.setColor(graphics2D.getColor());
     g.fillOval(ovo.getX1(), ovo.getY1(), ovo.getWidth(), ovo.getHeight());
    //g.drawLine(rek.getX1(), rek.getY1(), rek.getX2(), rek.getY1());
    //g.drawLine(rek.getX1(), rek.getY1(), rek.getX1(), rek.getY2());
    //g.drawLine(rek.getX2(), rek.getY2(), rek.getX2(), rek.getY1());
    // g.drawLine(rek.getX2(), rek.getY2(), rek.getX1(), rek.getY2());
 }
 
 /**
  * setting dot color
  * @param color color
  */
 public void color(Color color){
  graphics2D.setPaint(color);
  repaint();
 }
 }
```

Main class:

```js
package com.comp2526.assign2c.a.a00892238;


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * main class.
 * @author Fu Han
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */
public class Main {
  /**
   * tookit
   */
  private static final Toolkit TOOLKIT;

  static {
    TOOLKIT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  }
  /**
   * defaulth constructor.
   */
  private Main() {}

  /**
   * main method.
   * @param argv argv
   */
  public static void main(final String[] argv) {
    final ShapeFrame frame;

    frame = new ShapeFrame();
    position(frame);
    frame.init();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  /**
   * position for shapeframe.
   * @param frame Shapeframe.
   */
  private static void position(final JFrame frame) {
    final Dimension size;

    size = calculateScreenArea(0.80f,
      0.80f);
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setLocation(centreOnScreen(size));
  }

  /**
   * the amount of center on screen
   * @param size space size.
   * @return the complete calculated space.
   */
  public static Point centreOnScreen(final Dimension size) {
    final Dimension screenSize;

    if (size == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be null");
    }

    screenSize = TOOLKIT.getScreenSize();

    return (new Point((screenSize.width - size.width) / 2, (screenSize.height - size.height) / 2));
  }

  /**
   * method that calculating screen area.
   * @param widthPercent width percentage.
   * @param heightPercent height percentage.
   * @return dimension the dimension.
   */
  public static Dimension calculateScreenArea(final float widthPercent,
    final float heightPercent) {
    final Dimension screenSize;
    final Dimension area;
    final int width;
    final int height;
    final int size;

    if ((widthPercent <= 0.0f) || (widthPercent > 100.0f)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("widthPercent cannot be " +
        "<= 0 or > 100 - got: " +
        widthPercent);
    }

    if ((heightPercent <= 0.0f) || (heightPercent > 100.0f)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("heightPercent cannot be " +
        "<= 0 or > 100 - got: " +
        heightPercent);
    }

    screenSize = TOOLKIT.getScreenSize();
    width = (int)(screenSize.width * widthPercent);
    height = (int)(screenSize.height * heightPercent);
    size = Math.min(width,
      height);
    area = new Dimension(size,
      size);

    return (area);
  }
}
```

Rectangle class:

```js
package com.comp2526.assign2c.a.a00892238;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Rectangle extends Shape {

  // Initialize variables
  private int x1; // x coordinate of first endpoint
  private int y1; // y coordinate of first endpoint
  private int x2; // x coordinate of second endpoint
  private int y2; // y coordinate of second endpoint
  private Color colour; // colour of the shape

  // A no-parameter constructor that sets all the coordinates of the shape to
  // 0 and the
  // colour to Color.BLACK
  public Rectangle() {
    x1 = 0;
    y1 = 0;
    x2 = 0;
    y2 = 0;
    colour = Color.BLACK;
  }

  // A constructor that initializes the coordinates and colour to the values
  // of the
  // parameters supplied.
  public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color col) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.colour = col;
  }

  public void setX1(int x1) {
    this.x1 = x1;
  }

  public void setY1(int y1) {
    this.y1 = y1;
  }

  public void setX2(int x2) {
    this.x2 = x2;
  }

  public void setY2(int y2) {
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  public void setColor(Color colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  public int getX1() {
    return this.x1;
  }

  public int getY1() {
    return this.y1;
  }

  public int getX2() {
    return this.x2;
  }

  public int getY2() {
    return this.y2;
  }

  public Color getColor() {
    return this.colour;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return (Math.abs(x2 - x1));
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return (Math.abs(y2 - y1));
  }

  public int getUpperLeftX() {
    return (Math.min(x1, x2));
  }

  public int getUpperLeftY() {
    return (Math.min(y1, y2));
  }
}
```

Point class:

```js
package com.comp2526.assign2c.a.a00892238;
public class Point {
  private int x = 0;
  private int y = 0;

  public Point() {}

  public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

}
```

Oval class:

```js
package com.comp2526.assign2c.a.a00892238;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Oval {

  // Initialize variables
  private int x1; // x coordinate of first endpoint
  private int y1; // y coordinate of first endpoint
  private int x2; // x coordinate of second endpoint
  private int y2; // y coordinate of second endpoint
  private Color colour; // colour of the shape

  // A no-parameter constructor that sets all the coordinates of the shape to
  // 0 and the
  // colour to Color.BLACK
  public Oval() {
    x1 = 0;
    y1 = 0;
    x2 = 0;
    y2 = 0;
    colour = Color.BLACK;
  }

  // A constructor that initializes the coordinates and colour to the values
  // of the
  // parameters supplied.
  public Oval(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color col) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.colour = col;
  }

  public void setX1(int x1) {
    this.x1 = x1;
  }

  public void setY1(int y1) {
    this.y1 = y1;
  }

  public void setX2(int x2) {
    this.x2 = x2;
  }

  public void setY2(int y2) {
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  public void setColor(Color colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  public int getX1() {
    return this.x1;
  }

  public int getY1() {
    return this.y1;
  }

  public int getX2() {
    return this.x2;
  }

  public int getY2() {
    return this.y2;
  }

  public Color getColor() {
    return this.colour;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return (Math.abs(x2 - x1));
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return (Math.abs(y2 - y1));
  }

  public int getUpperLeftX() {
    return (Math.min(x1, x2));
  }

  public int getUpperLeftY() {
    return (Math.min(y1, y2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ShapeFrame class if you make your savebtn() method like this then your File->Save option will save the image where you pick from the save dialog, the other buttons and such you have to do but your File->Save option will save the file with this

```
public static void savebtn(DrawPad dp) {
        DrawPad dp1 = dp;
        //String sb = "gg";
/*
        public void save() throws IOException{
            ImageIO.write(paintImage, "PNG", new File("filename.png"));
        }*/
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));
        int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (retrieval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".png");
                //fw.write(sb.toString());
                //fw.close();
                File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                  String filePath = f.getPath();
                  if(!filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png"))
                  {
                      f = new File(filePath + ".png");
                  }
                ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) dp1.image, "PNG", f);
                //ImageIo.
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```